# Determine if a number is a runaround number

Tags: c++, algorithm

Definition of a runaround #:

- It is an integer with exactly N digits, each of which is between 1 and 9, inclusively.
- The digits form a sequence with each digit telling where the next digit in the sequence occurs. This is done by giving the number of digits to the right of the digit where the next digit in the sequence occurs. If necessary, counting wraps around from the rightmost digit back to the leftmost.
- The leftmost digit in the number is the first digit in the sequence, and the sequence must return to this digit after all digits in the number have been used exactly once.
- No digit will appear more than once in the number.

Checking for repeat digits isn't a problem, but I can't seem to come up with a good way to check for the "runaround" part. I'm looking more for suggestions/pseudo code than actual c++.

Comment: homework?  add appropriate tag if is...

Comment: http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/3/347.html

Comment: This seems to have a lot in common with permutation matrices.  Ignoring that though, it seems like it would be easy to test by keeping a bit mask and running it N times.  If every bit gets set, you're good.

Comment: Do you have an example of this?

Comment: Not sure how to reply to a person, but no it's not homework.
Example runaround numbers are 13 and 1263.

Comment: @Daniel: Homework and other meta-tags are now [discouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Comment: @Space: `[homework]` [is not dead yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/is-homework-an-exception)

Comment: @john it would be polite to upvote useful question.

Answer (score 1):

if you convert the integer into a string it shouldn't be any difficult: all you need is an operator[] (that the std::string class provides) and an array of boolean for recording which element has already been checked:

```
string value = input_integer;
vector<bool> checked;

int index = value[0];
checked[0] = true;
bool done = false;
while (!done) {
   index = get_wrapped_index(value, index);
   if (!checked[index])
      checked[index] = true;
   else 
      return false; // not a roundaround

   if allTrue(checked) && index == 0
      done = true;
}
return true;
```

You have to code get_wrapped_index(string s, index i), that must return the integer specified by s[i] given the right-wrapping costraint specified by the problem.

Comment: I think you'd want to preinitialise checked to a vector of n falses, where n is the number of digits in the number - otherwise a premature return to index 0 may not be picked up as erroneous.

Comment: Yes, of course, but if you use std::vector<bool> this is already done.

Comment: Since `value` is a standard string that does not have a `rotate_right_by` method, it would be better as `rotate_right_by(value,index)` as a free function --rather than giving weird ideas about deriving from `std::string` to add a method. Also, the signature of the function would provide more insight into your intended semantics: is it actually meant to rotate the string? or does it only update the `index`?

Comment: Since it looks like an homework, I didn't want to provide full details. That's why I stated "rough pseudocode" at the beginning. Anyway I agree that it could give weird ideas, I will modify the pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 rules laid out so just write code to check each rule.

- The number is N digits. Determine what N is. Could be done by converting to a string or a vector for each digit. You may need to use division by 10 and mod (%) 10 a few times.
- A method to move from one digit to the next. So if you are at digit position x with value y, you move to x+y mod N that is (x+y)%N. The first position is considered position 0, of course.
- You need to check that you touch every position, and also that you do not have a duplicate. This could be one check. If you reach a digit you have seen before you know you have the correct solution if and only if this is the Nth iteration and you are at index 0.

12 is failure. Because although it is after 2 iterations you do not reach index 0 but revisit index 1 (2 takes you from index 1 back to index 1)

11 is failure because you see another 1 when you have not had all your iterations yet.

123 is failure because you get back to 1 an iteration too early. You don't need to know you didn't see the 3, or that you got back to index 0, just that you saw another 1 too early.

285 works though. You see 2 then 5 then 8 then 2. You are at index 0 and have had 3 iterations.

You need to store a collection of seen digits. vector is slightly controversial, so you could use std::bitset or even just a bool[10] will do for this example, or vector. You could also use std::set, the latter case of which would allow you to check its size to see your iteration count.